# Azure: Read csv from blob storage based on header name not position

Tags: c#, azure

I have a requirement to read a csv file from Azure blob storage and load the contents into Azure Table storage. I did this part successfully and it works fine. My code detects the column values from csv based on the position of the column header but not based on the column name. So, I want to enhance it further so that my c# code should detect the column values based on header name not based on the column position. I explored the option of dictionary but i am not sure if it can be achieved using this.

CSV Content looks like this:

PartitionKey,RowKey,Ace,Age

TYSE,88010,A1,5

TYSE,88011,A2,4

Here is the core part of my code that does column assignment like col[0], col[1], col[2] etc..

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); 
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("testblobcontainer");
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("Test.csv");
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TestStorageTable");

int lineCount = 0;

using (var stream1 = blob.OpenRead())
{
    using (StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(stream1))
    {
        while (!reader1.EndOfStream)
        {
            lineCount++;
            reader1.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (lineCount > 0)
            {
                string[] cols = line.Split(',');
                TestLiveTbl TestEntity = new TestLiveTbl();

                if ((cols[0] != "PartitionKey"))
                {
                    string TempPartitionKey = cols[0].ToString();
                    string TempRowKey = cols[1].ToString();

                    TestEntity.TempPartKey = TempPartitionKey;
                    TestEntity.TempRwKey = TempRowKey;
                    TestEntity.Ace = cols[2].ToString();
                    TestEntity.Age = Convert.ToDouble(cols[3]);
                    TestEntity.AssignPartitionKey();
                    TestEntity.AssignRowKey();

                    TestLiveTbl TestEntityIns = RetrieveRecord(table, TempPartitionKey, TempRowKey);
                    if (TestEntityIns == null)
                    {
                        TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Insert(TestEntity);
                        table.Execute(tableOperation);
                        Console.WriteLine("Record inserted");

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. Maybe you could edit your question to include a sample of content you're importing? Also, I don't understand what you're doing with temporary partition/row key assignments.

Comment: Hi David, i edited my question... thank you

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You should use any library for this from NuGet? (for example - csvHelper: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Mapping by name can help You)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used DataTable and loading csv values into the datatable, then i am reading DT based on column name and loading into Azure table storage. It works fine irrespective of the column position.